# TypeError: user.sendMFACode is not a function - Redux Saga and AWS Amplify

Tags: redux-saga, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Using: [aws-amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) 0.3.3, aws-amplify-react-native 0.2.9., redux-saga 0.15.6

While calling the `Auth.confirmSignIn` using redux-saga:

`let confirmedUserData = yield call([Auth, Auth.confirmSignIn], userObj, authCode, 'SMS');`

Getting the following error:
**"TypeError: user.sendMFACode is not a function"**

The response object from `Auth.signIn` is the following: https://d.pr/AX6IQI. This response object is what gets passed to `Auth.confirmSignIn` as the user object. While looking into the response object, there is not `sendMFACode` function. Further, seeing the following: https://d.pr/i/gmzi0E which exists multiple times throughout the response object:

**"TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them"**

I'm not sure if the error above is relative to the "TypeError: user.sendMFACode is not a function" error as I'm not sure where the `sendMFACode` is supposed to live.

The `Auth.confirmSignIn` function looks like this: https://gist.github.com/grgaortiz/9a9dacefe1deca932396beea34ebebf2. You can see it trying to call the `sendMFACode` function from the response "user" object.

There is a [closed github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/192#issuecomment-389309056) but the resolution was to swap out redux-saga for redux-thunk which doesn't really crack the problem.